# Double Integral Confusion..

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

for the double integral $\iint$$5xye^{(-x^2)}dxdy$, are you able to pull out the $5y$ and then integrate over $xe^{(-x^2)}$? For the indefinite integral I got $5y(\left(\frac12\right)e^{(-x^2)})$, however the back of the book disagrees. Any tips on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: :what is region of integration

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $$\iint 5xye^{(-x^2)}\,dx\,dy=\int5y\left(\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx\right)dy.$$ The inside integral is doable via substitution and then you can integrate the result with respect to $y$.